# Ext JS Forms at multiple depth

Tags: extjs

So in an Ext js View I have a form which can potentially contain fields and multiple forms inside it and those forms that are contain by main form can also contain forms and fields. there is no limitation of how deep will the last form be. When I submit I want to get a thing like this

```
main-form
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    form-l2
    {
        key-l2:value-l2,
        form-l3
        {
            key-l3:value-l3,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

as an object.

Comment: what do you get if you try `getValues()` ?

Comment: I get a one level key value pairs

Comment: then you will need to override getValues of [Ext.form.Basic](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) to build a deeper object (and you should think about what form property should be the key)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, form cannot [contain another form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and in ExtJS, even if we could somehow trick it, it wouldn't play well and I doubt is is worth the effort.

Better would be to have one bounding form in which you'd implement the tree-like UI plus some custom methods (or overrides of the existing methods) to return the nested json made of the field values.